# How to change the age automatically every year

Tags: c++

i wrote this program, but i have a variable "age". how do i make it so that i do not have to change age of the dogs every year? In other words it should change automatically.

Comment: Did you forget to include the code in your question?

Comment: The age should be calculated as the current year minus the birth year, not hard-coded or updated periodically.

Comment: @Wyzard: Why does the question need code? It's quite clear what's being asked.

Answer (score 4):

instead of saving the age you should save the birthday, this way the age can be calculated when needed