# Change the age of the automatically every year

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the age automatically every year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444390/how-to-change-the-age-automatically-every-year)

I wrote this program, but I have a variable "age".  How do I make it so that I do not have to change age of the dogs every year?  In other words it should change automatically?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Dog//instance class
{
string Fam;
string & Name;
//string  Name;
string Otch;
static string mField;
unsigned int    Nagradi;
unsigned int    Age;
public:

Dog(string fam="", string otch="", string nam="", 
unsigned nagradi=0, unsigned age=0):Fam("")
    ,Name(Fam)
{
    cout << "Dog::Dog(" << nam << ")" << endl;
    Name = nam;
    Otch = otch;
    Fam  = fam;
    Nagradi = nagradi;
    Age = age;
}

Dog(Dog const & st): Name(Fam)//constructor
{
    cout << "Dog::Dog(copy:" << st.Name << ")" << endl;
    Name = st.Fam;
    Otch = st.Name;
    Fam  = st.Otch;
    Nagradi = st.Nagradi;
    Age = st.Age;
}

~Dog()//Destructor
{
    cout << "Dog::~Dog(" << Name << ")" << endl;
     system ("pause");
      }

void Show()
{
    cout<< Name << ' ' << Fam << ' ' << Otch <<
           " #" << Nagradi << " age:" << Age << endl;
}
};
```

Comment: -1 Edit your previous post to put the code in instead of asking a new question.  Search the web for "C++ get date".

Answer (score 5):

Store the birth date rather than the age, then calculate the age when you need it.

Just like someone said the last time you asked this question. Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: i wanted to include the code...i was having problems the first time. but i'll try your method. thank you very much

Comment: i found it. i put #define CurrentYear 2012, and used this to calculate the age. is there a better way? because this way i'd have to change the CurrentYear every year